# What sObject properties don't cause triggers to fire?

Tags: trigger

I recently discovered that updating your Chatter profile image won't cause the User trigger to fire (for fields SmallPhotoUrl or FullPhotoUrl). I was wondering what other fields, when updated, won't cause the sObject to which it is attached to fire any relevant triggers?

EDIT: On closer inspection the URLs themselves don't change at all when the image is changed, so I guess you wouldn't really expect the trigger to fire in that case. I'm going to edit the question to better reflect what is happening.

Comment: I'm starting to realize this question may really be better off as community wiki as there are probably a lot of possible answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's worth taking a look at [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).  It lists out step-by-step what happens when a trigger executes.  Specifically, the steps on what happens when workflows fire and the steps on rollup summaries and relations to parents/grandparents is interesting.

> If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a
> cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up
> summary field in the parent record. Parent record goes through save
> procedure.

So, updating the child inputs to a roll-up summary field can cause a trigger on an object to fire.

Also, checkout [Salesforce - Operations that Don't Invoke Triggers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm).

**Update** -- Added example with explanation.

Consider the following example with a Master detail between `Child` and `Parent` and the following:

- Number field on `Child` called `Num Field`
- Roll-up summary on `Parent` that sums `Num Field`

Write the following trigger on Parent__c:

```
trigger ParentTrigger on Parent__c (before update) {
    for (Parent__c p : Trigger.New) {
        p.addError('Not going to save');
    }
}
```

Now go into the new or edit page for your `Child` object and fill in a value for `Num Field` and save the record and see what happens.  You get:

> Error: Invalid Data.
>
> Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>
> Not going to save

Next, blank out the `Num Field` and save and see what happens.  No error is generated and the `Child` saves.

So when the child record is saved and the field feeds into the roll-up summary the parent trigger is executed.

Comment: Changing child records that feed into a rollup summary field can fire a trigger on the master? That surely doesn't sound right ?

Comment: @techtrekker - Yeah.  That's why I posted this.  Most people don't realize that.

Comment: Wow that is really cool. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Any child records that are reparented as a result of the merge operation do not fire triggers. 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm

Answer (score 4):

A change in the value of a Formula field won't cause the sObjects update triggers to fire.

I did find the idea [Fire Trigger on Formula Field value updates](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpL2).

Comment: I don't know if I'd want that by default...some of the data models can get pretty complex with lots of formulas used for convenience.

Comment: @PeterKnolle I agree, while it is an Idea, I'm not sure it is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

With Territory Management enabled, changing the all-mighty Opportunity field *TerritoryId* doesn't fire Opportunity triggers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to those already mentioned: sorting the order of Quote or Opportunity Line Items will not cause either the parent or child objects to trigger.  I can't find any documentation of this from Salesforce but it should be easy to verify by adding a trigger and then sorting line items.