# Number of SOQL Query

Tags: soql

I have a fundamental question about the how number of SOQL queries calulated in Salesforce.

I have inserted 50 Sample Accounts (Sample0, Sample2 ...Sample49) and trying to perform SOQL query:

`List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Sam%'];`

logs show the below limits:

`Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 50 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000`

Now, when i try to query and delete accounts:

`List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Sam%'];
 DELETE accs;`

The logs show:

`Number of SOQL queries: 2 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 50 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 50 out of 10000`

UPDATE: I am executing the code in Developer console with Execute Anonymous Window. Below is the code:

`/*list<Account> iacc = new List<Account>();
for(integer i=0; i<50; i++) {
    iacc.add(new Account(Name = 'Sample' + i));
}
insert iacc; */`

`List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Sam%'];
Delete accs;`

I would uncomment 'for loop' and insert statement for re-inserting the accounts later (i would comment SOQL and Delete statment that time)

I was expecting Number of SOQL queries to be still 1, but the limits show it as 2. I guess i am missing something fundamental about the behaviour of SOQL or DELETE. Can you please help me in understanding this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What code did you use to do this?

Comment: Are you doing this in one transaction (in which case 2 queries is expected) or two transactions? Please share the code you used.

Comment: Dan, Girbot - I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on `Account` that runs either `before delete` or `after delete`?

Comment: @DerekF, yes i had a before delete trigger on `Account` and additional `SOQL query` was being counted from that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did copy-paste your code snippet on my home dev org and it showed only 1 SOQL for me.
I would suggest you to check for:

- Triggers for this object
- Processes in process builder for this object (since process builder could run apex)
- Workflows since they could cause trigger invokations.
- not entirely sure but...flows?

I would suggest you to create a new dev org and try your code snippet there. It should show you only 1 query.

**Edited:** the author said that the additional SOQL query was because of before delete trigger(written in comments).

Comment: also rollup summaries

Comment: @kurunve do roll-up summaries count against query limits? O_o

Comment: no, but they may trigger one more update, which can eat query limit)

Comment: @kurunve are you sure? Could you please give me a link to it. I thought that roll-up summaries never cause update triggers(and it's logically correct - in other way it would be insane perform trigger every time the child's updated.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/do-changes-to-rollup-summary-fields-cause-triggers-to-fire

Comment: Thanks @EvAzi, i tried in new dev org. it showed me only one SOQL query. additional query was showing up because of a before delete trigger i had on Account. Thanks for pointing out.