# Does adding a detail record cause an update event on the master record?

Tags: apex, trigger, master-detail, before-trigger

**Background**

I have a `master-detail` relationship between two objects, let's call them:

- `parent__c`
- `child__c`

Once the `parent__c` record is in a certain `status__c` we block any changes using a `before update` trigger.

But this same `before update` trigger on the `parent__c` object is blocking `child__c` records from being added.

**Questions**

1. Is this an expected behaviour?
2. What is the usual pattern to enable this situation and workaround this behaviour?

Comment: Does the parent record have any summary rollup fields on it or do you have any triggers / workflow on the child to update data on the parent?

Comment: @MarkPond yes it does have rollup fields.

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an expected behaviour?

Yes, this can happen because of Process Builder updates, triggers, and rollup summary fields. See [Triggers and Order of Operation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

> What is the usual pattern to enable this situation and workaround this behaviour?

The usual solution is to write triggers to set static variables to allow conditional bypasses. The specific solution often depends on the specific problem, however.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. What the usual solution for allowing rollup summaries?

Comment: @Robs You'd probably want to check to see if that particular field was being updated, and if so, skip the error message. Each solution is likely going to be problem-dependent.

Comment: How do I `check to see if that particular field was being updated` when it's the addition of detail record that's causing the trigger to fire?

Comment: @Robs In the parent record, you'd do something like `for(parent__c record: trigger.new) { if(Trigger.oldmap.get(record.Id).RollupField__c != record.RollupField__c) { checkForErrors(record); } }` This is again just pseudocode, but should get you started, I think.

Comment: Of course! sorry, my brain just wasn't working!

Comment: @Robs No worries, we all have our moments.