# Opportunity After Update trigger fires Account Triggers - any way to disable it?

Tags: trigger

In one of my Oppty after update triggers, I found that the account triggers fire as well.

[image]

- Why is the account updated ? (I am not updating values on the account object)
- Is there a way to control the execution, so my account triggers (in this case) will not fire?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Dan Appleman's [Advanced Apex Programming book](http://advancedapex.com/).  He details a trigger pattern that handles this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good discussion [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/what-sobject-properties-dont-cause-triggers-to-fire) on what sobject properties do not cause triggers to fire which I think should answer your question.

In terms of controlling the execution, you could use a static class and variable to store some basic contextual information that informs you whether in this transaction the opportunity trigger has already fired, if so then do not run the trigger code.